# inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater() suddenly doesn't work

Tags: android

I updated SDK tools and some otherthings on Android SDK Manager and now the line in the title throws an error now. it used to work fine. I don't know why activity became ContextThemeWrapper.

Any idea what's happening here?

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Activity

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
```

Comment: how are you instantiating the class ?

Comment: @Blackbelt in the contractor of a class extending Spinner public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner 

 `public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   new CustomerMultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(context,
    R.layout.customer_spinner_adapter_view, new ArrayList<String>());`

Comment: is  `context`, `this` or `getActivity()` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt its instantiated like this `languageSpinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) ll.findViewById(R.id.lanaguage_spinner);`

Comment: where is getCustomView defined?

Comment: @Blackbelt it's defined in the adapter of the MultiSelectionSpinner `public class CustomerMultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: just use this `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`

Comment: what is `context`, and what makes you think it's an actiivty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found the dangers in assuming that a Context is always an Activity. Use `LayoutInflater.from(context)` instead.